# C++ Passing a template function to another function without specifying the template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

### Intro

Two weeks ago I started a new project and came along another idea for a project: a test runner for automating tests of template functions - which I'm currently working on.
The main reason behind all that is that I want to

1. learn more about (modern) C++ and
2. implement some stuff from my uni lectures.

Said test runner should be able to test a template function, i.e.:

```
// Said template function (*)
template <class T>
T add(T a, T b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

### Setup Explanation

In order to do so I created a class TestRunner (shown in the following) that gets a tuple of parameters via its constructor and has a friend (`run(...)`) that executed the test.

```
template <class... PS>
  class TestRunner {
  public:
    // constructors
    explicit TestRunner(std::tuple<PS...> paramSetTuple) : paramSets_(paramSetTuple) {}

    // ... other unimportant stuff ...
    
    // friends
    template <size_t idx, typename F, class... P>
    friend constexpr void run(TestRunner<P...> testRunner, F&& testFunc, std::string_view testFuncName);

  private:
    std::tuple<PS...> paramSets_;
  };
```

As seen here `run(...)` gets the an instance of TestRunner, a rvalue reference to the function that shall be tested and some string for a better console output.

(just FYI, but not important to the problem itself: The reason for making this friend function is that I want to implement different tests and I don't want to just copy paste the basic functionality behind `run(...)` as well as I want to created a macro that spares me of the `run(...)`'s last argument.)

### Finally, the problem itself:

I want to be able to pass `add(...)` to `run(...)` *without* specifying `add(...)`'s template parameter, because this template parameter should be specified automatically when I use the `add(...)` function in `run(...)`, which looks like this:

```
template <size_t idx = 0, typename F, ParameterSetConcept... P>
  constexpr void run(TestRunner<P...> testRunner, F&& testFunc, std::string_view testFuncName) {
      // ... some stuff to iterate through the tuple ...
      
      // ... some other stuff to get the input parameters for add(...) and it's expected output
      //     for now, let's just say the input is a tuple i.e. testInputs,
      //     and the expected output i.e. expectedOutput

      auto output = std::apply(std::forward<F>(testFunc), testInputs;
      if ( output == expectedOutput ) { 
        // this == is just an example for a successful test 
        // (more options will be implemented later)

        run<idx + 1>(testRunner, std::forward<F>(testFunc), testFuncName);
      } else {
        // ... some error output ... 
      }
  }
```

It be said that the iteration through tuples, and fetching of the tuple `testInputs` as well as the expected output `expextedOutput` work just fine.

Now what I need is to be able to call `run(...)` in the main (or a gtest) *without* specifying it's template parameter.
This may look something like this:

```
int main() {

  TestRunner testRunner(...); // init testRunner as it's supposed to be
  run(testRunner, add, "add");

  return 0;
}
```

Is there even a solution to this problem?
In advance: THANKS FOR ANY HELP!

#### Last Comments

I'm aware that the total setup of using such a 'complex' construct in a UnitTest as I mentioned before (gtest) might be a bad idea for the UnitTest concept itself, but I mainly do all this because I want to learn something about C++ and came along this problem.
Please don't judge ^^ I know that there is a option for value parameterized tests and even type parameterized tests in the gtest framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is,

```
auto call_add = [](auto&&... args){ return add(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
doSomethingWithAdd(call_add);
```

Of course, you can add a macro for it if it's too complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I wasn't able to try it out until now, since I had to rearrange some stuff in my project.
Now I tied your proposal and I wasn't able to solve my problem with it. 
I just completely edited the post in order to clarify what I'm looking for. 
I gave a description of the whole problem and some more explanations. Hopefully this clarifies the problem. I'd really appreciate any help! (:

Comment: @fajk Where exactly are you stuck with this implementation? `call_add` at this point captures all `add` overloads and is a lambda that can be passed to your unit test runner I think (but cmiiw).

Comment: EDIT: I think I just solved the problem myself: calling run(tr, [](auto&&... args){ return add(args...); }, "add"); let's my whole project compile and execute correctly (: 
I'm still not 100% sure if `std::forward` should be sued somehow, in order to ensure correct behavior with references. Can someone might help me with this?

Comment: @fakl Aha, figured: `decltype()` was missing. Glad it works now.

Comment: yeah, just before checking in here again I came to the same solution ^^ 
Thanks a lot! @lorro

Comment: fyi, I just saw that you missed the } in your answer. Just in case someone else visits this post later ... @lorro

Comment: @fakl Where exactly? (Did you scroll right? - there's a `{` before `return` and a `};` after `);`)

Comment: damn it, u r right ^^ I didn't see the scrollbar! @lorro